Can anyone think of a real situation in which the parameters of a uniform distribution need to be estimated?
(now with edits based on the responses)
I'm looking at the question of how to predict values from the continuous uniform distribution, based on samples from a continuous uniform distribution with unknown parameters (whuber gives a nice formulation in the responses).
There's an interesting objective Bayesian solution, with a fun pencil-and-paper derivation.
It's a good case to illustrate the benefits of Bayesian prediction.
But are there any examples where this might be used in the real world? I'd like to be able to mention an example in my presentation, or maybe even work on a real example.
The 'german tank problem' suggested in the responses by Ben and Nick is for a discrete random variable. I'm wondering if there are also any examples for a continuous random variable.
The random variable could be univariate, or some kind of multivariate generalisation...so in 2d it could be a circle or rectangle, I guess.
thanks

Does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem count?

On what data would the prediction be based?  Are you referring to constructing prediction limits from a sample from a Uniform$[a,b]$ distribution with one or both of the parameters $a,b$ unknown?  Or would you have something else in mind?

One kind of problem centres on buses, taxis, tanks, fighters you name it that have serial numbers 1 up. The task is estimate the total number ($=$ maximum) from observations. Adapting @whuber's notation the distribution is discrete uniform on $\lbrace 1, \cdots, b \rbrace$ and we have observations $1 \le x \le b$.

Ben and Nick: that's interesting, thanks. I was actually thinking of a continuous random variable, but maybe for large b the continuous solution would be a good approximation. whuber: yes, that's exactly it. I would call it constructing a predictive distribution, but I think that's the same thing. If you rewrite the problem with location and scale parameters, and use a 1/scale prior, there's a nice pencil-and-paper solution that looks like table mountain.

"Prediction limits" and "predictive distribution" are almost entirely different things.  It would help to read a clearer articulation of what you're aiming at.

@BenBolker: I had another thought. It seems to me that the german tank problem is an estimation problem, for estimating the maximum $b$, rather than being a prediction problem for the distribution of the next value.

@whuber: oh, that's interesting. I'm thinking about creating a predictive distribution, based on a sample from a uniform, where the parameters are unknown. So what I want could be written as $p(x_{n+1}|(x_1,...,x_n))$. So that would be predicting the number that the next tank might have, rather than predicting the posterior distribution for $b$. The predictive distribution doesn't sound very useful in the context of the tank problem.

So is what you are after a prediction interval? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval An interval which has a $c$% chance of containing the next observation? So you want an interval which may contain (with some confidence level) the S/N of the next captured/destroyed German tank? That indeed does not seem to have many practical applications?

@jginestet: I think one could say that the predictive distribution $p(x_{n+1}|x)$ is the collection of all prediction intervals. For the german tank problem, it doesn't seem very interesting. In general, predictive distributions are used when people care about what might happen next (e.g., in weather and climate forecasting, extreme value analysis, insurance risk modeling). There are various applications for the predictive distributions for the exponential, normal, Gumbel, and so on. My question is: can anyone think of an application for the predictive distribution for the continuous uniform?
